# Como fazer um form com JSF com um campo que pode ter quantos valores forem necessários?

Tags: java, jsf, formulário, framework

Levando em consideração a seguinte classe de entidade:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;



@Entity
@SequenceGenerator(name = "cliente_sequencia", sequenceName = "cliente_sequencia",
        allocationSize = 1, initialValue = 1)
public class Cliente implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "cliente_sequencia")
    private int id;
    private String cpf;  
    private String nome;
    private String email;  
    private List<String> telefones;   

    public Cliente(){
    }

    public Cliente(String cpf, String nome, String email, List<String> telefones) {
        this.cpf = cpf;
        this.nome = nome;
        this.email = email;
        this.telefones = telefones;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }


    public String getCpf() {
        return cpf;
    }

    public void setCpf(String cpf) {
        this.cpf = cpf;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public List<String> getTelefones() {
        return telefones;
    }

    public void setTelefones(List<String> telefones) {
        this.telefones = telefones;
    }
    public void addTelefone(String telefone) {
        telefones.add(telefone);
    }
    public void removeTelefone(String telefone) {
        telefones.add(telefone);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Cliente{" + "id=" + id + ", cpf=" + cpf + ", nome=" + nome + ", email=" + email + ", telefones=" + telefones + '}';
    }

}
```

Tendo esse controlador :

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class Controlador2 implements Serializable{

    private Cliente cliente =  new Cliente(); 
    @EJB
    private ClienteDAO servico = new ClienteDAO();

    private List<Cliente> todos = new ArrayList<>();

    public String redirecionar(){

        return "index.xhtml";
    }
    public String salvar(){
        servico.salvar(cliente);
        todos = servico.todos();
        return "listaTodos.xhtml";
    }

    public Cliente getCliente() {
        return cliente;
    }

    public void setCliente(Cliente cliente) {
        this.cliente = cliente;
    }

    public List<Cliente> todos() {
        return servico.todos();
    }

    public void setTodos(List<Cliente> todos) {
        this.todos = todos;
    }


}
```

Como eu poderia criar um formulário com jsf que tivesse um campo onde eu pudesse inserir uma lista de telefones? Nunca fiz algo do tipo!!

Comment: Você pode criar um input com um botão na frente, toda vez que preencher o telefone e clicar no botão ele add o valor na lista que está no seu Controller.

Comment: @DiegoAugusto Poderia me explicar como através de uma resposta parceiro?

Comment: Desculpe, mas estou um tanto apurado no momento. Básicamente seria um input com um botão ADD, toda vez que tu clicar no add vc faz um push na lista. Ou seja, vc precisa criar um método que quando vc clique no ADD vc passe o valor do input e faça o add na lista.

Comment: @DiegoAugusto Obrigado pela atenção vou ver se consigo fazer!!

Comment: Por nada, se ngm responder mais tarde tento elaborar uma resposta.

Answer (score 1):

Amigo, vc precisa de uma View, um aquivo .XHTML o qual conterá o código do formulário em questão, geralmente é criado e alocado na pasta WebContent do seu projeto Web.
Lembre-se, vc deverá seguir a hierarquia do arquivo XHML, como em arquivos HTML;

Sege o modelo básico de um arquivo XHTML, não irei fazê-lo por vc, se não perde a graça.

- O `<h:body></h:body>`, é o corpo;
- O `<h:form ></h:form>`, o formulário
- O `<h:outputLabel></h:outputLabel>` , é o que será mostrado, o rótulo de entrada
- O `<h:inputText></h:inputText>`, é a sua caixa de entrada.
- O "value" do imput text é onde vc irá fazer o binding com o seu controlador (named bean).

```
<h:body>
   <h:form > 
      <h:panelGrid>
        <h:outputLabel value="campo 01"/>
        <h:inputText id="campo01" value=""/>

        <h:outputLabel value="campo 02"/>
        <h:inputText id="campo02" value=""/>

        <h:outputLabel value="campo 03"/>
        <h:inputText id="campo03" value=""/>

        <h:outputLabel value="campo n"/>
        <h:inputText id="campoN" value=""/>

      </h:panelGrid>
   </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

ps: estude a documentação oficial.

espero tê-lo ajudado;